# Why does importing the numpy zeros function fail for parallelization using numba?

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, parallel-processing, numba

According to the [Numba docs](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/parallel.html#numba-parallel), numpy array creation functions `zeros` and `ones` should be supported. However, testing this with simple functions leads to a nopython error when I import the zeros function from numpy. However, if I do `import numpy as np` and use `np.zeros`, there is no problem. Is there some difference in the functions I'm getting from numpy? I'd prefer only to import the functions I need, rather than the entire numpy library.

This code snippet fails:

```
from numpy import array
from numpy import zeros
from numpy.random import rand
from numba import njit, prange

# @njit()
@njit(parallel=True)
def prange_test(A):
    s = 0
    z = zeros((3, 3))
    for i in prange(A.shape[0]):
        s += A[i]
    return s

A = rand(10)

test = prange_test(A)
```

This code snippet works:

```
from numpy import array
from numpy.random import rand
from numba import njit, prange
import numpy as np

@njit(parallel=True)
def prange_test(A):
    s = 0
    z = np.zeros((3, 3))
    for i in prange(A.shape[0]):
        s += A[i]
    return s

A = rand(10)

test = prange_test(A)
```

I'm using Numba version 0.35.0, Numpy version 1.13.2[image: This is the rather long Traceback I get]

Comment: And where is the copy of the Exception traceback error message, that the code generated? **Next**, you might have already found, the function does not "use" **`z`** at all. Yet, if you feel it is a good idea to spend time & resources on creating never used array, have you tried to remove this from the function and rather generate / allocate the **`z`** array outside of the `numba`-decorated code and rather pass that via its arguments `def prange_test( arrayA, arrayZ )`? **Next**, have you noticed, that the actual `numba.prange()` will not ever do any magic in your code, because of dependences?

Comment: I've edited the original question to attach the 76 line error message I get. I am well aware that the function does not use z, I just took the sample function from the numba documentation (just above section 1.9.3) for parallelization to see if I could actual initialize an array of zeros within a parallelized function.

Answer (score 0):

### Let's go step by step

**a )** the `@numba.njit( parallel = True )` decorator's **`parallel`** option is *(cit.) "**experimental**"* in its efforts to **auto-detect** chances in the code to introduce some form of parallelism.

**b )** the code is almost exactly the code-snippet from [`numba` documentation, using almost exactly the same `prange()`-constructor code-block, but inside an **`@autojit`** decorated example:](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.11/prange.html)

```
from numba import autojit, prange

@autojit
def parallel_sum(A):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in prange(A.shape[0]):
        sum += A[i]

    return sum
```

**c )** error message reports problems inside almost with such auto-detect transformation related to the **`line 12`** which only weakly referenced might be **`s += A[i]`**, referring to some kind of a problem inside the "automated-understanding" of the intent expressed in  the **Intermediate Representation** of the code-block, where the `prange`-index ought be used - **`Var($parfor_index_tuple_var.14)`** but some type-related or `tuple`-decoupling-related problem was not able to get resolved by **`numba.jit`**-LLVM translator. Yet, the traceback also mentions `call_parallel_gufunc` to have problems to detect the upper bound of the `prange`-constructor `stop = load_range( stop )`, whereas the numba documentation so far mentions that **only CPU-directed** parallel-code is supported ( not any { GPU | guvectorize | et al }-non-CPU-kernel(s) ), here a better documented MCVE altogether with matching error Traceback would be appreciated, instead of a weakly referring [PNG-picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTKMi.png)

**d )** last but not least, the numba requires as a mandatory step in the documentation the **`parallel=True`** to be used **only** *(cit.)* "***in conjunction with* `nopython=True`**"

---

### How to proceed?

1 ) test the above copied `numba`-published code as-is, to see, whether the newer release of `numba` still keeps all the promises that were already working in the previous releases. I.e. use `@numba.autojit`-decorator and re-run the exact code copy to `{ POSACK | NACK }-`this test.

2 ) test the code, POSACK-ed from step 1, this time under **`@numba.njit( parallel = True, nopython = True )`** decorator ( no other change except the decorator ) to 
`{ POSACK | NACK }-`influence of the decorator-policy.

3 ) test the code, POSACK-ed from step 2, this time with other modifications

---

### Conceptual remarks:

With all due respect to the numba-team, there could hardly be a worse example of **`parallel` and `prange()` anti-pattern** than this one.

Besides the awfully immense overhead costs of the [PAR]-process section setup and an absolutely nothing to efficiently compute in parallel ( just notice the actual value dependency-graph .. ) the [**criticism** on the Amdahl's Law initial, **add-on overheads-agnostic, formulation** shows](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3) how much one can pay for principally just worse than original performance. **Parallel process scheduling typically has exactly the opposite motivation.**

If indeed interested in smarter code-execution, use `numba.jit` having much better performance/cost ratio:

- shave off any residual type-analyses related parts of the IR-code using explicit announcements of the calling-interface signatures
- avoid memory allocations inside the performance-tuned code, rather pre-allocate and pass as another parameter
- extend calling interface, so as to avoid things well known at the caller side to be deferred into the numba-automated code-analyses

---

```
  @numba.jit( 'float64( float64[:], int64, float64[:,:] )', nogil = True, nopython = True )
  def prange_test( vectorA,       # 
                   vectorAshape0, # avoids numba-code to speculate on type
                   arrayZ         # avoids "local" new memory allocation
                   ):
      sum = 0
      ...
      return sum
```

---

### Performance?

```
 from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch()

 def a_just_vectorised_sum( vectorA ):
     return vectorA.sum()

 A = np.random.rand( 1000000 )

 aClk.start(); s = a_just_vectorised_sum( A ); aClk.stop()
 1145L
 1190L
 1188L
```

Benchmark. Always. Always on a real-world sized dataset. Never rely on a schoolbook sized artifacts, but go into real-world scales.

Results show that the **`1.000.000`** cell-sized vector took about `1,200 [us] ~ 0.0012 [s]` to `sum()`, **leaving less than about `1.2 [ns]` per cell `sum()`-ed** this sets a yardstick to compare any other implementation against.